# Finding all possible complex solutions to the system $xy = \sqrt 2(x + y)$, $yz = \sqrt 3(y + z)$, $zx = \sqrt 5(z + x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Find all possible complex solutions to:
> $$\begin{cases}xy = \sqrt 2(x + y) \\
> yz = \sqrt 3(y + z)\\
> zx = \sqrt 5(z + x)\end{cases}$$

I have some ideas:

$$xy-\sqrt 2y=\sqrt 2x\implies y=\frac{\sqrt 2x}{x-\sqrt 2} $$

and

$$yz-\sqrt 3y=\sqrt 3z\implies y=\frac{\sqrt 3z}{z-\sqrt 3} $$

and

$$xz-\sqrt 5x=\sqrt 5z\implies x=\frac{\sqrt 5z}{z-\sqrt 5} $$

So I got

$$y=\frac{\sqrt 2x}{x-\sqrt 2}=\frac{\sqrt 3z}{z-\sqrt 3}=\frac{\sqrt 2×\frac{\sqrt 5z}{z-\sqrt 5}}{\frac{\sqrt 5z}{z-\sqrt 5}-\sqrt 2}$$

From here we can go to a solution, but that brings up really scary equations.  Is there any clever way to solve this?  That is a minor Olympiad problem.

Answer (score 8):

Observe that,

If $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $z=0$, you will get $x=y=z=0$. So, we can assume $x,y,z\neq 0$.

$$\begin{cases}\frac 1x+\frac 1y=\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}\\
\frac 1y+\frac 1z=\frac {\sqrt 3}{3}\\ 
\frac 1x+\frac 1z=\frac {\sqrt 5}{5}\end{cases}\implies \frac 1x+\frac 1y+\frac 1z=\frac {\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}+\frac {\sqrt 3}{3}+\frac {\sqrt 5}{5}}{2}=a$$

Finally, we have

$$\frac 1x=a-\frac {\sqrt 3}{3}\implies x=\frac{1}{a-\frac {\sqrt 3}{3}}$$

Note that,  $y$ and $z$ can be found in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not so bad.

From the first equation $y=\frac{\sqrt{2} x}{x-\sqrt{2}}$; from the third $z=\frac{\sqrt{5} x}{x-\sqrt{5}}$

Plug in the second
$$\frac{x \left(\left(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{15}\right) x-2
   \sqrt{30}\right)}{\left(x-\sqrt{2}\right) \left(x-\sqrt{5}\right)}=0$$ So, if $x\neq 0$, then
$$x=\frac{2 \sqrt{30}}{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{15}}\qquad y=\frac{2 \sqrt{30}}{-\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{15}}\qquad z=\frac{2 \sqrt{30}}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{15}}$$